# Terraform template_file : Error: failed to render : <template_file>:16,32-33: Extra characters after interpolation expression;

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I tried to load my `buildspec.yml` file in my terraform aws codebuild project but it failed:

here is my buildspec :

```
version: 0.2
env:
  parameter-store:
    PS_ASSET_S3_URL : "${ps_asset_url}"

phases:

  pre_build:
    on-failure: ABORT 
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
    
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
```

```
data "template_file" "buildspec" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/buildspec.yml")}"
}
```

and in codebuild section:

```
 source {
    buildspec           = data.template_file.buildspec.rendered 
    git_clone_depth     = 0
    insecure_ssl        = false
    report_build_status = false
    type                = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }
```

```
│ Error: failed to render : <template_file>:16,32-33: Extra characters after interpolation expression; Expected a closing brace to end the interpolation expression, but found extra characters.
│
│   with module.pipeline.data.template_file.buildspec,
│   on ../../../../modules/cicd_ecs_github_embed/main.tf line 172, in data "template_file" "buildspec":
│  172: data "template_file" "buildspec" {
│
```

Answer (score 0):

by searching more I found template_file use to see files as a template and except some placeholder like `${var}` to fill it. and my file has some `$var` placeholder that would be filled from CodeBuild!

So I decide to don't use template_file for this step because i didn't want to pass any params to it at this stage.

So I moved to use another terraform object local_file :

```
data "local_file" "buildspec_local" {
    filename = "${path.module}/buildspec.yml.tmpl"
}
```

and then losing in using `content` property in codebuild:

```
source {
    buildspec           = data.local_file.buildspec_local.content
    git_clone_depth     = 0
    insecure_ssl        = false
    report_build_status = false
    type                = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }
```

**Update 1 :**

I found in my case the error pointed to this line :
`IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}`
because terraform expects to see variable as this format: `${var}` but I have a `:` and it raised error. The solution I found is to escape this part of code by terraform by using double `$` . final code is here :
buildspec:

```
- IMAGE_TAG=$${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
```

and using template_file to load it without error:

```
data "template_file" "buildspec" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/buildspec.yml")}"
  vars = {
  #feed dynamic variables I need 
  ps_asset_s3_bucket="${var.ps_asset_s3_bucket_key}"
  ...
  }
```

Comment: If that YAML file is statically-configured in your repository along with your Terraform configuration files, you can skip using the data source entirely and just write `buildspec = file("${path.module}/buildspec.yml.tmpl")` directly. The `local_file` data source would be needed only for files created dynamically as part of the `terraform apply` step.

Comment: Thanx @MartinAtkins. That's great infromation

Comment: @MartinAtkins How can I feed my `buildspec.yml` file using `template_file` ?
i need to serve it with some parameters both give me errors.

I want to feed `${ps_asset_url}` via terraform but feed other keys like  `${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}` in my aws CodeBuild process

Comment: @MartinAtkins tnx i found a solution i escaped it by $$ : `$${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}`